# the navigation content's title generated by drupal book module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

the book navigation block content's title generated by drupal book module which is not have the title tip and the title is too long. how to trim it. and how to overwrite this specific block.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have two options:

1) edit book_block() in modules/book/book.module and change the title hardcoded.

2) use [yourtheme_preprocess_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7) to hook on the block's preprocess (in template.php of your theme) and check for the block's module and delta, and change the title there.

Comment: You really shouldn't hack the core